# How to parse attributes in a collection using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, xml, vb.net

Please see the XML below.  Comparable_Sale is a repeating item.  I am using new NewtonSoft’s Json parser and I need to be able to get the value of _Description attribute where the _type attribute equals a particular string value such as “GrossBuildingArea” from the  element.

I have used the code below to parse property values with newtsonsoft, but I can’t figure out how to get at the attributes.

```
<COMPARABLE_SALE PropertySequenceIdentifier="3" ProjectName="Villages of Devinshire" ProjectPhaseIdentifier="1" PropertySalesAmount="132500" SalesPricePerGrossLivingAreaAmount="109.32" DataSourceDescription="FMLS, 5559496;DOM 80" DataSourceVerificationDescription="Tax Recs/2ndGen/Deeds" SalesPriceTotalAdjustmentPositiveIndicator="N" SalePriceTotalAdjustmentAmount="-1500" SalesPriceTotalAdjustmentGrossPercent="1.1" SalePriceTotalAdjustmentNetPercent="1.1" AdjustedSalesPriceAmount="131000">
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type="GrossBuildingArea"_Description="1,254"/>
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type="BasementArea" _Description="1,254 Sq.Ft."/>
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type="BasementFinish" _Description="1rr2ba4o"/>
</COMPARABLE_SALE>
```

This code gets me to the properties, but I can't see how to get at the attributes.

```
for each item in   jobject.Children(Of JObject)()
    For Each [property]   In item.Children(Of JProperty)()
        If [property].Value.Type = JTokenType.[String] Then
            Dim newItem = New xmlRootValues()
            newItem.Name = [property].Name
            newItem.Value = [property].Value.ToString()
            lstValues.Add(newItem)
        End If
    Next
 next
```

Any help in either (C# or VB.net) would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chaos

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use LINQ to XML?

Comment: I have to do a lot of parsing on this document and I am serializing the xml into a Jobject with Newtonsoft in other places and i would like to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

To work with xml use an xml api like [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Here you have an example in C#:

```
var xml = @"<COMPARABLE_SALE PropertySequenceIdentifier=""3"" ProjectName=""Villages of Devinshire"" ProjectPhaseIdentifier=""1"" PropertySalesAmount=""132500"" SalesPricePerGrossLivingAreaAmount=""109.32"" DataSourceDescription=""FMLS, 5559496;DOM 80"" DataSourceVerificationDescription=""Tax Recs/2ndGen/Deeds"" SalesPriceTotalAdjustmentPositiveIndicator=""N"" SalePriceTotalAdjustmentAmount=""-1500"" SalesPriceTotalAdjustmentGrossPercent=""1.1"" SalePriceTotalAdjustmentNetPercent=""1.1"" AdjustedSalesPriceAmount=""131000"">
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type=""GrossBuildingArea"" _Description=""1,254""/>
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type=""BasementArea"" _Description=""1,254 Sq.Ft.""/>
<SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT _Type=""BasementFinish"" _Description=""1rr2ba4o""/>
</COMPARABLE_SALE>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var description = xDoc.Root.Elements("SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT")
                           .First(e => e.Attribute("_Type").Value == "GrossBuildingArea")
                           .Attribute("_Description")
                           .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In linq to xml you can also use Descendants and foreach to get all values for same element.

```
var obj = from item in xDoc.Descendants("SALE_PRICE_ADJUSTMENT")
                  select new
                      {
                          _Descr = item.Attribute("_Description").Value,
                          _Type = item.Attribute("_Type").Value
                      };
```